# How to search from React component rendered HTML string?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am working on a react-based table, which should support search functionality. Pseudo code like below:

```
export default class MyTable {
  constructor() {
    this.onSearch = (event) => {
      const value = event.target.value;
      /* stuck here */
    }
  }

  return (
    <MySearch onSearch={this.onSearch} />
    <MyTableBody />
  );
}
```

MyTableBody is responsible to translate text into `<tr><td>` HTML elements. I am stuck at two points:

1. How can I get `MyTableBody` rendered HTML string so that I can use it in
   `this.onSearch` method?
2. How to retrieve text only from HTML string?
   Just like the `text()` method used in `jest/enzyme`.

Answer (score 0):

What you did was what we would normally do with JQuery.

With React, it's bit different.

```
export default class MyTable {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        keyword: undefined
        }
  }

  onSearch = (event) => {
      this.setState({keyword: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <MySearch onSearch={this.onSearch.bind(this)} />
            <MyTableBody searchKeyword={this.state.keyword} />  
    )
  } 


}
```

1. "onSearch" should be called when you typing in the textbox inside 'MySearch' component.
2. Now 'searchKeyword' prop gets updated in the MyTableBody component through the state variable 'keyword'
3. Then you must have a filter method in the MyTableBody component to filter the Data object/array used to render the table.

**I have not tested this but concept should be like that**

You should change the way you think when working with React.

We should use the re-rendering functionality to do the DOM manipulation. 
You never have to use something like JQuery ever again.